# Delete Last 6 Rows From Multiple .txt Files

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have never done a batch file before. I have a few dozen .txt files sitting in a folder (ex. C:\files).

The files all end with 6 rows of text that need to be deleted. A sample would be (note spaces in first line):

```
   var...
'ascending';...
'LIT-xxx,LIT-xxx...
setfunction...
0.33...
getdate...
```

Additionally, I would like the "new" files to overwrite the current files so that the file names and directory do not change.

```
abs 10.txt
him 4.txt
lab 18.txt
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code snippet does exactly what you want, deleting the last six lines from text files:

```dos
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

rem // Define constants here:
set "FILES=C:\files\*.txt" & rem // (specify file location and pattern)
set /A "LINES=-6"          & rem /* (specify number of lines to delete;
                             rem     positive number: delete from begin,
                             rem     negative number: delete from end) */

rem // Standard `for` loop to resolve file pattern:
for %%F in ("%FILES%") do (
    rem // Get the count of lines for the current file:
    for /F %%N in ('^< "%%~F" find /C /V ""') do set "COUNT=%%N"
    rem // Initialise a line index:
    set /A "INDEX=-LINES"
    rem /* Enumerate all lines of the current file, preserving empty ones
    rem    by preceding each with a line number, so no line appears empty
    rem    to the `for /F` loop; the line number is split off later on;
    rem    in addition, the current file is emptied after being read: */
    for /F "delims=" %%L in ('
        findstr /N /R "^" "%%~F" ^& ^> "%%~F" break
    ') do (
        rem // Increment index, get text of currently iterated line:
        set /A "INDEX+=1" & set "LINE=%%L"
        rem // Toggle delayed expansion to preserve exclamation marks:
        setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
        rem // Check index value and write to current file conditionally:
        if !INDEX! GTR 0 if !INDEX! LEQ !COUNT! (
            rem // Split off line number from line text:
            >> "%%~F" echo(!LINE:*:=!
        )
        endlocal
    )
)

endlocal
exit /B
```

This approach does not use temporary files in order to avoid any name conflicts. However, due to the fact that there are multiple file write operations for every single file, the overall performance is a bit worse than when writing all data to a temporary file at once and moving it back onto the original file.

Comment: Thanks for downvoting without telling me why!!

Comment: Not sure why you were downvoted either. First, I appreciate all of your explanation in your code it was helpful. Additionally, it took a minute or so to run the script (which you pointed out the performance would be worse anyway) but it worked perfectly. It removed the bottom 6 lines from all files, kept the original files in the folder without any temp ones, and was very easy in that I did not have to specify the names of each text file. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Backup your original files to a different backup folder, then run this script:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
pushd "%temp%\Test"
for %%G in ("*.txt") do (set "break="
    (for /f "delims=|" %%H in (%%~G) do (
        if not defined break (
            echo %%H | findstr /r /b /c:"[ ]*var.*" >nul && set break=TRUE || echo %%H )
    )) >> %%~nG_mod.txt
    del %%~G & ren %%~nG_mod.txt %%G )
popd
exit /b
```

It assumed:

- your 6 rows of text always start from `[any number of spaces]var[any text]` row, as you posted in the question, where only one string of such kind is present in any file
- other 5 bottom rows don't need to match in every file
- you save the files to filter in `%temp%\Test`, and there are no other unrelated files in that dir.

Comment: I tried to run the script. It did not give any errors, however it created separate files in the folder (abs 10_mod, etc.) which had only the text: abs. In the original file, nothing was removed.

Comment: You likely spelled 1st var incorrectly, since it contains spaces. You didn't clarify as well, if the 6 rows are the same in each file.

Comment: What do you mean? I changed your code to: if not "%%H"=="   var" (echo %% etc. This was because the text in the files does not have the three dots after it but instead have lots of random text. It DOES include the spaces with the "var" though. Does it need the entire line of text?

Comment: @Zach Ford You should specify such info in Question, otherwise its not clear, what `   var...` means. I updated the script, it works well and fast here. Let me know if any issues.

Comment: Sorry, an ellipsis is a pretty common punctuation that indicates text is omitted. Since I used it on each line I figured it was clear enough. Additionally, I asked in my question to have the "new" files overwrite the old ones and thus not create new files which your script continues to do. Even so, I tried your edit and now get "The system cannot find the file abs." Followed by "Could Not Find C:\files\abs". I'm not quite sure what the "%temp%\Test" is supposed to mean but I changed it to "C:\files".

Comment: @Zach Ford Did you read the text below the script? A user is always expected to read the script before running, adapt it to their own paths, and debug to run on own OS version, if any errors. The path you gave won't likely be used by a next user reading this thread, and SO read millions.